# Xamarin Forms: progressbar and its update

Tags: xamarin.forms, progress-bar

a question about progressbar. In my application I have a form where I update a list of people in the database and I want to show a progress bar. For each record I update the progress bar. The problem is the progress bar doesn't show anything. The code is:

```
double progress = Convert.ToDouble(e.CurrentRecord) / Convert.ToDouble(e.TotalRecord);
await this.progress1.ProgressTo(progress, 250, Easing.Linear);
```

I tried

```
this.progress1.Progress = progress;
```

but the result is the same. Any suggestion? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue to create a **ViewModel** for that; all values come from the ViewModel. When I call an **async** function I always added `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.